# Anchor id deselect google maps api search box

Tags: html, css

I'm making a new website for fun in french. Search box for google maps is working on IE but not In Chrome when i add an anchor.
www.nightdrink.fr
My trouble is when i add a new anchor to go to my map, both links are working fine (trouver une épicerie/Voir la carte) but its deselects the search box of google maps.
I have to hold click button to type in.
If i remove the anchor, the links dont work anymore , but the search box will work...

Code used:

```
<li><a href="#features1">Trouver une épicerie</a></li>
<a href="#features1"></li><h4>Voir la carte</h4></li>
<section id="features1" class="features1">
```

Any Ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there seems to be an error in your HTML (second line). Maybe you meant something like this:

```
<li><a href="#features1">Trouver une épicerie</a></li>
<li><a href="#features1">Voir la carte</a></li>
<section id="features1" class="features1">
```

About the search box, I think you should use javascript/jquery to control anchor click and focus the searchbox. Otherwise, the click would always steal the focus from the searchbox.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i found a solution that's working I used

```
setInterval(function(){
var focusbox;
focusbox = document.getElementById("pac-input");
focusbox.focus();
});
```

My trouble is now i have other texts fields on the webpage, and now they can't be filled and all redirects automatically to the google maps searchbox ...
Is there anyway to dissociate this ??
thanks